# Subtraction in NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I want an NSPredicate like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude - %@) < %@",coordsLatitude, kMaxLatLong];
```

I basically want to find GPS coords in Core Data that are within a certain distance from `userLocation`.

- `latitude` is the latitude attribute of each gps entity.
- `coordsLatitude` is the latitude of userLocation.
- `kMaxLatLong` is set to 1

I'm getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with this line. I'm thinking it's due to my predicate just being badly formed, in particular the subtraction operator. However, I could not find anything stating how to use subtraction with NSPredicates, nor with NSExpressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do this the other way around.

Work out the minimum and maximum latitude and then use the predicate to find everything between.

i.e.

```
float coordsLatitude = //whatever

float minLatitude = coordsLatitude - kMaxLatLong;
float maxLatitude = coordsLatitude + kMaxLatLong;

NSPredicate *minPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude >= %f", minLatitude];
NSPredicate *maxPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude <= %f", maxLatitude];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubPredicates:@[minPredicate, maxPredicate]];
```

Then use the compoundPredicate in your fetch request.

Comment: OK, I'm going to try this out - makes perfect sense. However, do you know if there is a way to use basic math operators directly in the predicate? Just curious as I looked and couldn't find anything, and it seems pretty basic... I also now realize I'd need to stick an absolute value function in there as well.

Comment: I haven't heard of one. Although, anywhere you would want to use a basic math operator you can just do the calculation outside the predicate like I have done here.

Comment: Here is some in-depth NSPredicate filtering that may be useful in performing more complex queries like abs() of a property: http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1677163679/creating-an-advanced-nspredicateeditorrowtemplate